# Rust zip file corruption

Tags: rust, zip

I have to zip one folder that has more folders and more files in it, this is the code I have, and its weird, because when I open the `.zip` file with Winrar or File Explorer, it seems to be a perfectly working `.zip` file, but when I open the file with 7zip, it appears to be corrupted.

This is the code:

```rust
fn walk_dir(path: &str, zip: &mut ZipWriter<File>, options: FileOptions, path_cache: &str) -> io::Result<()> {
    let entries = fs::read_dir(path)?;
    for entry in entries {
        let entry = entry?;
        let entry_path = entry.path();
        let metadata = fs::metadata(&entry_path)?;
        let entry_actual_path = Path::new(path_cache).join(entry.file_name().to_str().unwrap());
        let entry_path_str = entry_path.as_path().to_str().unwrap();
        let entry_actual_path_str = entry_actual_path.as_path().to_str().unwrap();
        if metadata.is_dir() {
            zip.add_directory(entry_actual_path_str, options)?;
            walk_dir(entry_path_str, zip, options, entry_actual_path_str)?;
        } else {
            zip.start_file(entry_actual_path_str, options)?;
            let mut file = File::open(&entry_path)?;
            let mut buffer = BUFFER.lock().unwrap();
            buffer.clear();
            file.read_to_end(&mut buffer)?;
            zip.write_all(&buffer)?;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I found out that instead of / or \ in the paths, there are this characters: ``.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I'm just trying to create a zip file that works well, but it just wont. I also tried with different compression methods, but none of those works.

Comment: This seems like it should be a bug report against the crate you're using to create ZIP archives.

Comment: Maybe, but I'd say he's doing the responsible thing and assuming it's his *own* code first before blaming the library.  Still, a post on the crate's forums/github/whatever seems appropriate.